# formula for differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Prove the formula
$$
f(x+\pi)-f(x)
=
-\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\int_0^{\pi} f(t+x)\cos((2m+1)t)\: dt
$$
assuming $f\colon[x,\,x+\pi]\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable in $(x,\,x+\pi)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** [The Fourier series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_wave)
$$ g(t)=\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{\sin((2m+1)t)}{2m+1} $$
is constantly equal to $\frac{\pi}{4}$ for $t\in(0,\pi)$, since $g(t)=\text{Im}\text{ arctanh}(e^{it})$. Now use integration by parts.

Comment: ok, fine, but how do we know that $\sum\int=\int\sum$ in this case?