# the sum-int exchange

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

Why is the sum-int exchange allowed in the following equality ($f$ is a $C^1$ function):
$$
\sum_{m\geq 1}
\int_0^{\pi}f'(t)
\frac{\sin((2m+1)t)}{2m+1}
dt
=
\int_0^{\pi}f'(t)
\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{\sin((2m+1)t)}{2m+1}
dt
$$

This is a part of solution to another problem:
[formula for differentiable function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1790534/formula-for-differentiable-function)

Comment: If $f $ were $C^2$ then you could integrate by parts and then use the M-test. Without that I think the derivation will be more difficult because you do not have absolute pointwise convergence of the sum. You essentially would like to proceed weak convergence of the sum.